# How can I initialize my custom IdIOHandler fields?

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-10.3-rio

This is blowing my mind... I just want to make a new `IdIOHandler`, and, as usual, I need to do some initialization in the constructor... Normally, I override the constructor of the base class, but this `TIdIOHandlerStack` which I inherit from, is far from "normal" ! It has no constructor to override, and is not known (to me) how it is created.

```
  TIdEnhancedIOHandler = class(TIdIOHandlerStack)
  private
    FSendBuffer: TIdBytes;
    FSendBuff: TDataStream;
  public
    constructor Create;  // <-- I tested all the variations here, but non of them work
    destructor  Destroy; override;
  end;

  implementation

  constructor TIdEnhancedIOHandler.Create;
  begin
   inherited Create;
   FSendBuff:= TDataStream.Create(@SendBuffer);
  end;

  destructor TIdEnhancedIOHandler.Destroy;
  begin
   FSendBuff.Free;
   inherited;
  end;

  initialization

    TIdEnhancedIOHandler.SetDefaultClass;
```

Where should I put my intitialization code so that it is executed when a new instance of `TIdEnhancedIOHandler` is created BY DEFAULT in all Indy Components which use IOHandlers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it... It was the `InitComponent` method that I must override.

```
  TIdEnhancedIOHandler = class(TIdIOHandlerStack)
  private
    FSendBuffer: TIdBytes;
    FSendBuff: TDataStream;
  public
    procedure   InitComponent; override;
    destructor  Destroy; override;
  end;

  implementation

procedure TIdEnhancedIOHandler.InitComponent;
begin
 inherited;
 FSendBuff:= TDataStream.Create(@SendBuffer);
end;
```

Comment: Overriding `InitComponent()` is the preferred way in Indy 10, yes. It exists because Delphi and Delphi.NET manage construction differently, so a common initialization method was needed. In Indy 11, support for .NET will be dropped, so `InitComponent()` will go away as well, in favor of normal constructors. But even in Indy 10, you *can* override the constructor, like with any other component, eg: `constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;`